# Ionic Angular routeprovider not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic App where i run in some trouble.
I'm new to AngularJS and Ionic.

The user needs to be logged in to use the app. To check this an apicall to my server is called on entry of the app. If the user is not logged in, the app will show a modal where the user can login.

But in the small second that the apicall is made you see the "inside" of the app (restricted pages).
To avoid this i want to place a screen where the app checks if the user is logged in. And if the user is logged in, the screen needs to send the user further in the app.

The problem in this is that the app doesn't send the user on. I replaced all the code with a simple a href (ui-sref) but that doesn't work either.

The funny, weird part is that if i run it in my browser it works. But on my mobile(android) is doesn't do anything.

I tried it with a function with $location.path but i doesn't send me anywhere. It does set the path.

I tried $apply, $digest, $window.location.href .... etc etc. none worked.

If i don't use the wait screen everything works fine.

### wait.html

```
<a ui-sref='app.proposals({"favorite" : 0})'>Continue</a>
```

### RouteProvider

```
matcher.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,     $ionicConfigProvider)
{
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position("bottom");
  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.style("standard");

  $stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.proposals', {
    url: '/proposals/:favorite',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/proposals.html',
        controller: 'ProposalsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.proposal', {
    url: '/proposal/:title/:id/:url',
    views: {
      'menuContent' : {
        templateUrl: 'templates/proposal.html',
        controller: 'ProposalCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('wait',{
    url: '/wait',
    templateUrl: 'templates/wait.html',
    controller: 'WaitCtrl'
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/proposals/0');
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/wait');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, now, the best way to solve this would be use a better practice. Your application follows the standard Authentication Flow. Now, according to me, wouldn't it be better if you just animate the current view in context. This will serve two purposes

- reduce the render-load time;
- get rid of you problem.

According to me, the problem here is that when you make the API call, Ionic tries to get hold of a cached page. The best way to fix it to have a default base check; point to `index.html`, the `IndexController` checks is the user is logged in, if it is, use `$state.go("STATE_NAME")` to go to the logged in state, otherwise, go to a state where you login.

Trust me when I say this: not only will this be easier, it'll also be more maintainable once the application code really builds up.

Should you require any further clarifications and/or code samples, just comment here. I haven't included them as it's trivial and extrapolates the logic and the syntax you're already familiar with.

Comment: Thank for your reply. But how do i set the base check to `index.html`? This is an one page app. Everything happens in `index.html`.